# sorted list and drop down list in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics, data-binding

I have an method which returns a sortedList and i want to datasource it to a Dropdownlist.

i am using

```
DropDownList1.DataSource=stList;
DropDownList1.DataValueField=stList.ContainsValue();
DropDownList1.DataTextField=stList.ContainsKey();
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

But it gives an error: No overload method for containsKey and containsValue.
 How to populate this sorted table in drop down list?

Answer (score 10):

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = stList;
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Key";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Value";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

**[Edit]**

Adding tested working code:

```
SortedList<int, string> list = new SortedList<int, string>();
list.Add(1, "Test1");
list.Add(2, "Test2");

dropDownList.DataTextField = "Value";
dropDownList.DataValueField = "Key";
dropDownList.DataSource = list;
dropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks.. I use this but it displays System.Collection.SortedList in the drop down list.

Comment: It works no errors but in the drop down list instead of showing values it shows System.Collection.SortedList

Comment: @user1 - I tested this code. Updated my answer with copy/pasted code that I used and verified that it is working.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dim SL As New SortedList(Of String, String)
    SL.Add("A", "1")
    SL.Add("B", "2")

    DD1.DataSource = SL
    DD1.DataTextField = "key"
    DD1.DataValueField = "value"
    DD1.DataBind()
```