# how can i sort drop down items in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a drop down in asp.net that I added some things to from the database.  Also in the end I added some things manually.  Now I need to sort these items in a quick and simple way.  The drop down selected value is as number.

Is object link useful for my problem?  If your answer is yes, please describe.

Comment: Can you paste your UI code that you are using to create your dropdown? Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a small utility method like this to sort the items of DropDownList.

```
public static void SortListControl(ListControl control, bool isAscending)
{
    List<ListItem> collection;

    if (isAscending)
        collection = control.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Select(x => x)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Text)
            .ToList();
    else
        collection = control.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Select(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Text)
            .ToList();

    control.Items.Clear();

    foreach (ListItem item in collection)
        control.Items.Add(item);
}
```

### Usage

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));

    // Sort the DropDownList's Items by descending
    SortListControl(MyDropDownList, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without code it is going to be hard to answer your question.  But this is most likely what you are looking for. [IEnumerable.OrderBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a key.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
        SortedList<int, string> mySortedList = new SortedList<int, string>();
        mySortedList.Add(1, "Hi");
        mySortedList.Add(2, "Hello");
        mySortedList.Add(3, "German");

        dropDownList1.DataTextField = "Value";
        dropDownList1.DataValueField = "Key";
        dropDownList1.DataSource = mySortedList;
        dropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort dropdownlist items in simple way. First fill the dataset through adapter then fill dataview from dataset and sort the dataview with required column.Finally bind the dropdownlist with dataview.

Step 1: Create connection object and then fill dataset using dataadapter

Example:

I) creating connection object as follows:

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;Database=dbname;Integrated Security=true"); //if windows authentication 
(or) 
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;Database=dbname;user id=xxx;pwd=xxx"); //if sql authentication
```

II) creating object for adapter class with query and connection object as two parameters as follows:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter("query",con);
```

Step 2: Create DataSet object and fill it using adapter object as follows:

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
sda.fill(ds);// filling sda data into dataset using fill method of adapter class
```

Step 3: Check dataset is non-empty or not. If non-empty then create DataView object and fill it with sorted option and bind dropdownlist as follows:

```
if(ds.Tables[0].rows.count>0)
{
    DataView dv=new DataView();
    dv.Table=ds.Tables[0]; // filling dataview with dataset
    dv.sort="columnname";
    DropDownList1.DataSource=dv;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField="columnname";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,"select");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up as a SortedList and then just call the list.Sort() method.

You would set the list up as your datasource, and use the key/value fields as the DataTextField and DataValueField.

[StackOverflow question on sorted list as datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040474/sorted-list-and-drop-down-list-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp)